# Showing a window centered

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, grid, centering

I need to show a `Window` centered in the second column of my `Grid`. Since it is a `Window`, I can't add it directly to the Grid through XAML. Can I programmatically find out the center of my Grid's second column, so that I move my Window there before showing it?

My second window is just a fancy little message box. I was earlier trying to convert it to a `UserControl` instead of a `Window`, so that I could put it directly inside the Grid's second column, but then I can't do `ShowDialog()` on it. I must wait for the user to click OK before moving ahead.

Comment: Care to leave a comment, Mr. Downvoter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking for an answer, here is what I ended up with:

```
private void CenterWindowInRightPane(Window window, UIElement rightPane)
{
    Point loc = rightPane.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    w.Left = (this.Left + loc.X) + (rightPane.ActualWidth - w.ActualWidth) / 2;
    w.Top = (this.Top + loc.Y) + (rightPane.ActualHeight - w.ActualHeight) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that MDI interface suits for your case: http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com

Comment: Not really. My second window is nothing more than a small fancy message box. No MDI stuff or anything.

Comment: You can get **left top** corner coodrinates and size of `Grid` and `Message box` and adjust last's position with some simple mathematical expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Popup` to which you set the grid as `PlacementTarget` and set `Placement=Center`

Comment: Does `Popup` block code from executing like `ShowDialog()` does?